# Contextual freezing decline after exposure to CS (Fear Conditioning)

Tags: memory, conditioning, behavioural-neuroscience

I am trying to find the literature or a phenomenon name to explain the following condition,

Animals are trained with cued fear conditioning (Context A), then at testing, they have two consecutive cases. They can be either tested in the training context (Context A, contextual fear testing) first, or they can be tested in a different context (Context B, cue fear at testing) first. During contextual testing, animals show more freezing if they were not subjected to context B testing first. Does this indicate some form of contextual extinction or enhancing the specificity of freezing to CS while being in context B?

Comment: Hello, I think this is extinction, however if an unfamiliar context was able to diminish the response, than the conditioning was not context-dependent.